# How do you print multiple formula fields on a NetSuite Saved Search using the Advanced PDF/HTML Templates tool?

Tags: netsuite

In NetSuite, how do you print multiple formula fields from a Saved Search using the Advanced PDF/HTML Templates tool?  If I use the tag ${result.formulatext} the first formula field prints.  But what if I have 2 formula fields?  What would the second formula field be called?

I have tried ${result.formulatext0} ${result.formulatext1} and ${result.formulatext2}.  All of these produced a general error when trying to print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You nearly had it! Try `${result.formulatext_1}`.

You can also see what the field reference should be if you go to the add field window in WYSIWYG mode, click on the Add Field button:

[image]

then scroll to the bottom where the search fields are:

[image]

Comment: That didn't work for me either.  Still gives a general error.  I also tried '${result.formulatext_0}' and '${result.formulatext_2}'

Comment: The Windhover, You didn't say that you tried ${result.formulatext_1}. The docs say it will actually print the **second** field with '_1' suffix. And use ${result.formulatext} for the first one. Any additional ones just carry on with suffix increments.

Comment: Thanks @DmitriyKravchuk.  I didn't actually even go to the docs for it - do you have a link?  Also OP, see additional info added to my answer - hope it helps!

Comment: @Krypton, make sure to login to NS first, then open this link https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/63077/kw/

Comment: Thanks @DmitriyKravchuk.  Looking at that made me realize another possible issue: we've assumed that OP had two text formulas, but if his first formula is text and the second is a currency, number or date formula, then the second would be referenced with `${result.formulacurrency}` ...etc.  You can have one formula of each type before needing any `_x` suffixes appended.  (Probably not the issue, but added here for completeness.)

Comment: Yeah, the names could confuse. OP got something going wrong, there's no other way to get the field, if he's in fact looking for a second text formula field.

Comment: I can see in the documentation that you posted that this is the correct answer, so I accepted your answer.  But for some reason I'm still getting a java.lang.ArraryIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 just like when I try any other tag.  I'm very sure that the saved search has 2 formula text fields and my code is exactly matching what you posted and what's in the documentation.  I think there must be something in the template that's somehow incompatible with having multiple formula text tags.  I can't thing of anything else it could be. Probably a question for NetSuite support.

Comment: FYI, I ended up using formulanumeric and formulacurrency fields as a second and third formula field. Luckily, enough of the data was simply numeric.  So I just used formulacurrency and then edited the data with Freemarker to appear as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a name to the custom formula field you created by using 'custom label' and you can access it using this name.

Comment: This didn't work.  Have you tried it before?  That only works in SuiteScript, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you use saved searches from the UI, the approach suggested by @Kripton with _1, _2 and so on is the correct one.

If you are creating the search in suitescript you can append a "_" and a unique identifier after formulatext. For example:

```
column=new nlobjSearchColumn("formulatext_externalid");
column.setFormula("{item.externalid}");
columns.push(column);
```

In this case the field is available as `${result.formulatext_externalid}`.

Thanks to Scott of Netsuite Professionals for this hint.